# Как получить относительный путь из события click для ссылки?

Tags: javascript, html, link

У меня стоит прослушивание

```
href[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault()

                    console.log(' href',e.currentTarget.href)
                });
```

всё работает но я получаю полный путь такого типа

http://localhost:8888/backend/gallery

Как мне получить относительный путь который указан в href ?

backend/gallery

Я объект посмотрел события. нашёл там только baseURI

Comment: e.location.pathName

Answer (score 1):

Выкусить, на основании `window.location.origin`

```js
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const link = e.currentTarget.href;
  console.log('link', link);
  const relLink = link.substring(window.location.origin.length);
  console.log('relLink', relLink);
});
```

```html
<a href="test" id="link">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, получить с помощью метода `getAttribute()`:

```js
document.getElementById('identifier').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = this.getAttribute('href');
});
```

[Подробная информация на сайте MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)